# Solve the warning issues when start emacs in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, auctex

My Emacs in Ubuntu always shows warnings below which is quite annoying.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/AROT/.emacs.d/init.el’:

error: Key sequence RET o starts with non-prefix key RET

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Then I followed the instruction and start emacs with command `emacs --debug-init` and saw the following info:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "tex-site")
  require(tex-site)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-267398> nil "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6/auctex-autoloads.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 10037
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6/auctex-autoloads.el" "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6/auctex-autoloads.el" nil t)
  load("/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6/auctex-autoloads" nil t)
  package--activate-autoloads-and-load-path(#s(package-desc :name auctex :version (11 88 6) :summary "Integrated environment for *TeX*" :reqs nil :kind nil :archive nil :dir "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6" :extras ((:url . "http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/")) :signed nil))
  package--load-files-for-activation(#s(package-desc :name auctex :version (11 88 6) :summary "Integrated environment for *TeX*" :reqs nil :kind nil :archive nil :dir "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6" :extras ((:url . "http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/")) :signed nil) nil)
  package-activate-1(#s(package-desc :name auctex :version (11 88 6) :summary "Integrated environment for *TeX*" :reqs nil :kind nil :archive nil :dir "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.88.6" :extras ((:url . "http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/")) :signed nil) nil deps)
  package-activate(auctex)
  package-initialize()
  byte-code("\302\303!\210\302\304!\210\305\306\307\310#\210\311\312\010\"\021\313 \207" [prelude-dir package-user-dir require cl package add-to-list package-archives ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t expand-file-name "elpa" package-initialize] 4)
  require(prelude-packages)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4156
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/AROT/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/AROT/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/AROT/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x25ec51>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Since I only have little knowledge of LISP, could anyone help me on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: is this perlude installed? you seem to have the latex packages missing. if you don't use that perhaps try a fresh install of emacs. If you do the method to debug the .emacs configuration is by commenting section by section and reloading. try commenting out the `latex` configuration  (i.e.  'require(tex-site))or alternatively install the package from elpa.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @manandearth ! I have fixed the error by reinstalling of auctex from source.